# nginx proxy redirecting request to different proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have three LXC containers (CN1, CN2, CN3).  They each run their own Apache instance and have their own networking, so each container has their own private IP.

I set up all containers to listen on the private IP only for Apache.  I also set up Nginx to act as a proxy from the host machine to direct any traffic based on the domain requested.

So, I have web1 -> CN1 (10.0.3.2), web2 -> CN2 (10.0.3.3), web3 -> CN3 (10.0.3.4).

When I go to web1, it shows the right page.  When I go to web2, it shows the right page.  When I go to web3, however, it shows web2's page.

Here's my Nginx server configs:

**web2**

```
server {
        server_name web2;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://10.0.3.3:802;
        }
}
```

**web3**

```
server {
        server_name web3;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://10.0.3.4:804;
        }
}
```

Apache's running on web3 and I get get the page when I telnet to it from the host machine itself:

```
root@SKYNet:/etc/nginx/sites-available# telnet 10.0.3.4 804
Trying 10.0.3.4...
Connected to 10.0.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: web3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 26 May 2013 17:00:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sun, 26 May 2013 16:27:58 GMT
ETag: "20457c-b1-4dda183dd360e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 177
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug

It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

I can also ping it from my home machine, and also from external sites that allow you to ping websites.  I even had a friend test it and it displayed the same thing (web2's index file instead of its own).

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to enable the Nginx config.

Assuming your sites-available configs are stored in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and Nginx reads from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` to see what servers to handle, do this:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/server_config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server_config
```

Then restart or reload Nginx.